# I want to combine multiple rows that have a missing column id into one row. I am trying to use pandas for this

Tags: pandas, merge, concatenation

| Column_id | statements |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | My dog |
| Nan | ate |
| Nan | a bone |
| a2 | an apple, |
| Nan | banana & |
| Nan | orange |

The original dataframe is called df. I would like the statement rows where column_id is missing to merge into one. The resulting data frame would look like this:

| Column_id | statements |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | My dog ate a bone |
| a2 | an apple, banana & orange |

Comment: `df['statements'].groupby(df['Column_id'].ffill()).agg(' '.join).reset_index()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75489804/20877866

@rhug123 can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the way to go about it and posting the solution to help someone stuck on the same problem:

```py
df_new = {'Column_id': 'first', 
         'statements': lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna())}
df.groupby(df.Column_id.notnull().cumsum().rename(None)).agg(df_new)
```