# How to compare rows within the same dataframe and create a new column for similar rows

Tags: pandas, row, isin

| obj_id | Column B | Colunm C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | cat | bat |
| a2 | bat | man |
| r1 | man | apple |
| r2 | apple | cat |

The orignal dataframe (above) is called df

I am trying to make a new colunm called new_obj_id where if rows in column B match any row of col C the new_obj_id should then have values of obj_id that match col B

| obj_id | Column B | Colunm C | new_obj_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | cat | bat | a2 |
| a2 | bat | man | r1 |
| r1 | man | apple | r2 |
| r2 | apple | cat | a1 |

This is the expected table

This is what I tried but couldn't get through:

```
dataframe1['new_obj_id'] = dataframe1.apply(lambda x: x['obj_id'] 
                           if x['Column_B'] in x['Column C']
                           else 'none', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['new_obj_id'] = df['Column C'].map(dict(zip(df['Column B'],df['obj_id'])))
```

Output:

```
0    a2
1    r1
2    r2
3    a1
```

Comment: I am just stuck with this one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75585726/new-to-pandas-i-want-all-the-values-main-category-to-be-included-in-subcategory

any help will be greatly appreciated