# New to pandas: I want all the values main category to be included in subcategory by using pandas

Tags: pandas, join, startswith

I have a table that looks like:

| id | string |
| --- | --- |
| 3.ab.3. | axz |
| 3.ab.3.a. | b |
| 3.ab.3.b. | c |
| 3.ab.4. | dog |
| 3.ab.4.a. | e |
| 3.ab.4.b. | f |
| 3.ab.4.b.1 | g |
| 3.ab.4.b.2 | h |

What I expect is the subcategory should have the string from its main category so 3.ab.3.a should have everything from 3.ab.3. and then the get rid of 3.ab.3.

| id | string |
| --- | --- |
| 3.ab.3.a. | axzb |
| 3.ab.3.b. | axzc |
| 3.ab.4.a. | doge |
| 3.ab.4.b.1 | dogfg |
| 3.ab.4.b.2 | dogfh |

I tried using .join and .startswith but couldn't get through

Comment: Can these categories be nested to any depth, or only one deep?

Comment: thank you Nick for your prompt reply, any depth. For example if we have rows 3.ab.3.a1 ,3.ab.3.a2 it should have everything from 3.ab.3. and 3.ab.3.a. and then we can get rid of 3.ab.3. and 3.ab.3.a. I have updated the final output table for a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = df.sort_values('id')['id'].str.split('.',n = 3).str[:3].str.join('')

s2 = s.ne(s.shift())

df.assign(string = df['string'].where(s2).groupby(s).ffill().add(df['string'])).loc[~s2]
```

Output:

```
           id string
1   3.ab.3.a.   axzb
2   3.ab.3.b.   axzc
4   3.ab.4.a.   doge
5   3.ab.4.b.   dogf
6  3.ab.4.b.1   dogg
7  3.ab.4.b.2   dogh
```